# I used git reflog and git reset on commit, have I negatively effected someone else's branch?

Tags: git, workflow

I made:

1. Committed on wrong branch
2. Git reset hard HEAD~1
3. I lost my changed files so I ran git reflog
4. I then git reset [commitId] - I realized that was not my commit so I stashed it...

Have I broken someone else's branch/commit history due to that?

Answer (score 2):

No. All this so far is happening on your local copy of the repository.

With Git you have a complete copy of the remote repository, including all the commits. You work on this local copy and then `git push` your changes to the remote, and `git pull` their changes down to yours. Every other command only affects your local repository.

Even if you were to `git push` now, Git will stop you because your local version of the branch has "diverged" meaning it's no longer a simple matter of placing your new commits on top of theirs. Just don't make habit of doing `git push --force`.

The simplest way to fix a branch you've mistakenly changed is to return it back to its remote version. Assuming your remote is `origin`...

```
git branch -f some_branch origin/some_branch.
```

See ["Working With Remotes"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and ["Remote Branches"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) in the Pro Git book for more.